# what does the `?` operator mean in C++?

Tags: c++

I was just reading some articles on Wikipedia involving some code in C++, but I was unfamiliar with one of the operators used, `?`. Here's the context in which it was used:

```
unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n) {
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1); 
}
```

Comment: google "conditional operator" or "ternary operator"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Comment: Same as IF statement. It means ..
if(n==0) 
return 1; 
else 
return (n * factorial(n - 1));

Comment: Excuse me, but there's no need to downvote this question. I did look to see if it had already been answered, but the problem was I was using the word operator, so the answer was excluded.

Comment: For what little it's worth, even googling "c++ question mark" gets useful results right away (including that other stackoverlfow question as the first result).

Answer (score 1):

```
condition ? true-outcome : false-outcome
```

Same as:

```
if (n == 0) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Not exactly the same, you can't use if statements as an expression.

Comment: In particular, tenaries can be used to initialize a const variable.